# matlab interactive contour plot

Tags: matlab, plot, interactive, contour

I have a set of data, or spectra, for various x-y coordinates.

Looks something like this:

```
x       y       spectrum x              spectrum y
-14 -18 35.0286000000000    330.643000000000
-14 -18 33.6069000000000    311.247000000000
-14 -18 32.1849000000000    251.419000000000
-14 -18 30.7628000000000    205.673000000000
-14 -18 29.3404000000000    152.912000000000
-14 -18 27.9178000000000    144.101000000000
-14 -18 26.4949000000000    135.292000000000
-14 -18 25.0719000000000    133.514000000000
-14 -16 35.0286000000000    353.507000000000
-14 -16 33.6069000000000    320.039000000000
-14 -16 32.1849000000000    272.517000000000
-14 -16 30.7628000000000    198.642000000000
-14 -16 29.3404000000000    163.458000000000
-14 -16 27.9178000000000    135.314000000000
-14 -16 26.4949000000000    147.592000000000
-14 -16 25.0719000000000    114.190000000000
```

And so on.

I wrote a program to take a slope from a segment of each spectra and make a new matrix that looks like this:

```
x       y       slope
-14 -18 0.650084924302224
-14 -16 0.751250946346182
-14 -14 0.0666371921219543
-14 -12 0.703160656652351
-14 -10 1.04017251503861
```

and so on.

I then make x, y, and z matrices from that matrix and plot using `[C,h] = contourfm(x,y,z)`.

What I'm interested in is a program where I can click on the contour plot and pull up a plot of an individual spectrum at the point nearest to the spot where I clicked. This would be very nice in the analysis of my data. Is this remotely possible? Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you'll probably need to build a GUI, but the following might also be satisfactory to you. Start with the function like  [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html). For example, `[x,y] = ginput(n)`  enables you to identify n points from the current axes and returns their x- and y-coordinates in the x and y column vectors. Pressing the Return key will terminate the input before entering n points. Then from these x,y coordinates, use `find` to plot the relevant part of the data you have.

Comment: Thank you, the ginput function is immensely useful. I was able to write a program that takes the ginput data, converts each point to the nearest actual x-y point, and plots the data for each of those points. The programming is pretty poor and has to be adjusted based on size and spacing of the map, but it works! I was also able to add a legend to the figure, but that was probably more trouble than it it was worth. I'd post the function, but it's not very pretty.